# VPN connects but no remote LAN access

Tags: networking, ssh, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I need to use ssh to access a cluster through a VPN. I am getting connection to VPN but cant access the cluster via ssh and neither ping to other remote ips.

I already searched and think is related to routing, but I had no sucess. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Output of ifconfig -a:

```
enp3s0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        ether 84:7b:eb:e6:94:48  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Loopback Local)
        RX packets 405  bytes 28332 (28.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 405  bytes 28332 (28.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ppp0: flags=4305  mtu 1400
        inet 172.23.22.120  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 172.23.0.5
        ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Protocolo Ponto-a-Ponto)
        RX packets 45  bytes 2864 (2.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60  bytes 7998 (7.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.15.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255
        inet6 2804:1b1:1181:ac73:3520:988d:48c2:7f1d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
        inet6 2804:1b1:1181:ac73:b1b4:3639:2b5b:ee81  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0
        inet6 fe80::aefb:f867:3897:cfd5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 28:56:5a:e9:aa:bf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 623546  bytes 815011367 (815.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 354679  bytes 52570743 (52.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Output of ip route:

```
default via 192.168.15.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
150.161.70.99 via 192.168.15.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static src 192.168.15.2 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.23.0.5 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 172.23.22.120 metric 50 
192.168.15.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.15.2 metric 600 
192.168.15.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static scope link metric 600
```

When I try to ping to 172.23.0.5:

```
PING 172.23.0.5 (172.23.0.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 172.23.0.5 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9199ms
```

Comment: Please include the output of `ip route` as well. And it's prefered to have text, not images...

Comment: You only have route towards 172.23.0.5, not the entire subnet. You should be able to ping 172.23.0.5 to verify that the VPN is up. What is the expected remote subnet?

Comment: I am not having success when trying to ping to 172.23.0.5

Comment: No, of course. Because you don't have a route against it. As it looks to me you have a tunnell with a end adress that can't reach the destination. I don't know ppp/pptp well enough to aid more than the general pointer here - but I believe the output will be useful to people more knowledgeable :)